# Laravel 4.x :Validation input file doesn't work

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, laravel-4

Hey everyones: I've got a problem here! I'm doing my project using laravel framework. I've got a problem when I try to validate an input files. I made a simple site for testing with a same problem. Here's my Route:

```
Route::get('test','TestController@uploadFile');

Route::post('test','TestController@uploadFile');
```

Here's my controller:

```
class TestController extends Controller{
public function uploadFile(){
    return View::make('test');
}

public function pUploadFile(){
    try {
        $file=Input::file('file');
        $validator=Validator::make(array('file' => $file ),array('file' =>'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:3072'));
        if($validator->fails()){
            return View::make('test')->withErrors($validator);
        }
        $destinationPath = "uploads";
        $extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename='testfile'.$extension;
        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        if($upload_success)
            return 'succeeded';
        return 'failed';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
}
```

And here's my blade.php file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>  
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="{{Asset('test')}}" id="form-register"   enctype="multipart/form-data">     
            <h2>Choose an image</h2>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
            {{$errors->first('file')}}
            <button>Upload</btn>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I chose a swf file with size:66mb and push the button, I got an error:

Warning: POST Content-Length of 64859333 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

It shouldn't cross over the validation rules! Why is that? Can anyboby help me?
ps:Sorry if my english is terrible :D

Thank you very much all you guys. It works!!! But now the new problem has coming. We can't control people when they choose a large file than 'post_max_size'. lol

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP configuration only allows for a maximum of 8MB to be uploaded. Adjust the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini.

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 128M
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not validation rules problem its related to settings you have in there.

Make sure you update post_max_size and max_file_uploads in php.ini to a larger value.

max_file_uploads = 256
 post_max_size= 256

You can find where is your php.ini file with phpinfo() function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

`post_max_size integer`

> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also
>   affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger
>   than upload_max_filesize. If memory limit is enabled by your configure
>   script, memory_limit also affects file uploading. Generally speaking,
>   memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size. When an integer is
>   used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described
>   in this FAQ, may also be used. If the size of post data is greater
>   than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty.
>   This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the $_GET
>   variable to the script processing the data, i.e. , and then checking if
>   $_GET['processed'] is set.

```
 max_file_uploads integer
```

> The maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded simultaneously.
>   Starting with PHP 5.3.4, upload fields left blank on submission do not
>   count towards this limit.